# Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml: root config contains unknown keys: deploy script environment

Tags: maven, amazon-ec2, gitlab, devops, continuous-deployment

I am getting the following error while committing the below .yml file:

> Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml: root config contains unknown keys: deploy  script environment

```
variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: " -s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test

deploy:
  stage: production
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600  ~/.ssh/id_rsa

    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

script:
    - bash ./gitlab-deploy/.gitlab-deploy.prod.sh

environment:

     name: production
     url: http://myurl.com:81
```

I am trying to deploy a Maven project from GitLab to AWS EC2.
Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Check your indentation. It should be like

```
deploy:
  stage: production
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - bash ./gitlab-deploy/.gitlab-deploy.prod.sh
  environment:
     name: production
     url: http://myurl.com:81
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your `deploy` job, this line looks suspect:

```
- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```

See how there is a single quote there?

Answer (score -1):

In your "deploy" job, try to change "before_script" by "script". Why configfure a "before_script" part without "script" ??